# python for loop one-liner invoked from bash command line yields invalid syntax, but list comprehension works fine

Tags: python, bash

I'm not sure why

```
$ echo -e "test1\ntest2\ntest3" | python -c "import sys; for i in sys.stdin: print(i)"
```

yields invalid syntax:

```
      File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; for i in sys.stdin: print(i)
                ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

it works fine when using list comprehension:

```
$ echo -e "test1\ntest2\ntest3" | python -c "import sys; [print(i) for i in sys.stdin]"
```

results in:

```
   test1

   test2

   test3
```

Comment: You can make it work if you put line breaks and indentation in: `echo -e "test1\ntest2\ntest3" | python -c $'import sys\nfor i in sys.stdin:\n\tprint(i)'`

Comment: That said, `echo -e` is bad form in the first place. `printf '%s\n' test1 test2 test3` is much better form -- or `printf '%b\n' 'test1\ntest2\ntest3'` if one can't change the string to be formatted/printed. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: @slothrop thanks, I was wondering what alternative separator to ';' would be in this case. '\n' seems a bit harder to read at first, but maybe it's a matter of getting used to it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for pointing this out, I've had no idea about this issue before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A statement in Python is either a single compound statement or one or more simple statements separated by `;`s. Compound statements are those that consist of a `:`-terminated line followed by one or more additional statements. You can't join them with a `;` because it would be ambiguous whether the semicolon was part of a nested block or terminating a compound statement.

From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html

```
statement: compound_stmt  | simple_stmts 

simple_stmts:
    | simple_stmt !';' NEWLINE  # Not needed, there for speedup
    | ';'.simple_stmt+ [';'] NEWLINE 

simple_stmt:
    | assignment
    | star_expressions 
    | return_stmt
    | import_stmt
    | raise_stmt
    | 'pass' 
    | del_stmt
    | yield_stmt
    | assert_stmt
    | 'break' 
    | 'continue' 
    | global_stmt
    | nonlocal_stmt

compound_stmt:
    | function_def
    | if_stmt
    | class_def
    | with_stmt
    | for_stmt
    | try_stmt
    | while_stmt
    | match_stmt
```

Comment: that explains it, thank you and thanks for the referencing the python's grammar